# ResponseEntity.ok() without response body?

Tags: rest, spring-rest

How can i return a ResponseEntity with 200 status code and no body ?

I have a Http PUT method and i dont want to return a response body. I want to return only the status code.

Comment: Did you try setting the body as `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/do/something")
public ResponseEntity doSomething() {
  return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```